# Differences in re.findall and re.finditer -- bug in Python 2.7 re module?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

While demonstrating Python's regex functionality, I wrote a small program to compare the return values of `re.search()`, `re.findall()` and `re.finditer()`. I'm aware that `re.search()` will only find one match per line and that `re.findall()` only returns the matched substring(s) and not any location information. However, I was surprised see to see that the matched substring can differ between the three functions.

Code ([available on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/palday/7805267)):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# License: CC-BY-NC-SA 3.0

import re
import codecs

# download kate_chopin_the_awakening_and_other_short_stories.txt
# from Project Gutenberg:
# http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/160.txt.utf-8
# with wget:
# wget http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/160.txt.utf-8 -O kate_chopin_the_awakening_and_other_short_stories.txt


# match for something o'clock, with valid numerical time or
# any English word with proper capitalization

oclock = re.compile(r"""
                    (
                          [A-Z]?[a-z]+ # word mit max. 1 capital letter
                        | 1[012]       # 10,11,12
                        | [1-9]        # 1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9
                    )
                    \s
                    o'clock""",
                    re.VERBOSE)

path = "kate_chopin_the_awakening_and_other_short_stories.txt"

print
print "re.search()"
print
print u"{:>6} {:>6} {:>6}\t{}".format("Line","Start","End","Match")
print u"{:=>6} {:=>6} {:=>6}\t{}".format('','','','=====')

with  codecs.open(path,mode='r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(f):
        atime = oclock.search(line)
        if  atime:
            print u"{:>6} {:>6} {:>6}\t{}".format(lineno,
                                            atime.start(),
                                            atime.end(),
                                            atime.group())


print
print "re.findall()"
print
print u"{:>6} {:>6} {:>6}\t{}".format("Line","Start","End","Match")
print u"{:=>6} {:=>6} {:=>6}\t{}".format('','','','=====')
with  codecs.open(path,mode='r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(f):
        times = oclock.findall(line)
        if times:
            print u"{:>6} {:>6} {:>6}\t{}".format(lineno,
                                            '',
                                            '',
                                            ' '.join(times))


print
print "re.finditer()"
print
print u"{:>6} {:>6} {:>6}\t{}".format("Line","Start","End","Match")
print u"{:=>6} {:=>6} {:=>6}\t{}".format('','','','=====')
with  codecs.open(path,mode='r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(f):
        times = oclock.finditer(line)
        for m in times:
            print u"{:>6} {:>6} {:>6}\t{}".format(lineno,
                                            m.start(),
                                            m.end(),
                                            m.group())
```

and Output (tested on Python 2.7.3 and 2.7.5):

```
re.search()

  Line  Start    End    Match
====== ====== ======    =====
   248      7     21    eleven o'clock
  1520     24     35    one o'clock
  1975     21     33    nine o'clock
  2106      4     16    four o'clock
  4443     19     30    ten o'clock

re.findall()

  Line  Start    End    Match
====== ====== ======    =====
   248                  eleven
  1520                  one
  1975                  nine
  2106                  four
  4443                  ten

re.finditer()

  Line  Start    End    Match
====== ====== ======    =====
   248      7     21    eleven o'clock
  1520     24     35    one o'clock
  1975     21     33    nine o'clock
  2106      4     16    four o'clock
  4443     19     30    ten o'clock
```

What am I missing something here? Why doesn't `re.findall()` return the `o'clock` bit?

Comment: hard long read for a simple question (to figure out if my question would duplicate). Couldn't the long example code be boiled down to 3 simple lines or so with plain example literals to show the issue well to the readers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [`re.findall` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

> ... If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of **groups**; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.

The `pattern` contains only one group; `findall` returns a list of the group.

---

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('abc', 'abc')
['abc']
>>> re.findall('a(b)c', 'abc')
['b']
>>> re.findall('a(b)(c)', 'abc')
[('b', 'c')]
```

Using non-capturing version of parentheses:

```
>>> re.findall('a(?:b)c', 'abc')
['abc']
```